# One interface for both MongoDB and Google BigTable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any interface or "mapping" stack, that works fine with both MongoDB and BigTable from GAE? I'd prefer document-oriented one.

I know theres [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) with plugins (or providers) for both but I dont think these can be considered as stable. And DataMapper is also relation-database oriented.

Is there anything?

Comment: Can be also in Python or Java

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about ruby, but [django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel) is a well-regarded project that does this in python. the current backends i know of are mongo, the gae datastore, simpledb, and cassandra. there are probably others out there too.